# Dimension of a product vector space with constraint

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_1$, $V_2$, $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over **F**.

For linear maps $A: V_1\rightarrow W$ and $B: V_2\rightarrow W$, we can define a subspace of $V_1 \times V_2$ by

$V_1 \times_W V_2 := \{(v_1,v_2)$ in $V_1 \times V_2 $ | $ A(v_1)=B(v_2)\} $

In this case, how can I prove the equality **dim($V_1 \times_W V_2$) = dim($V_1$) + dim($V_2$) - dim(range$A$ + range$B$)?**

Without such $ A(v_1)=B(v_2)$ constraint, product $V_1 \times V_2$ vector space has a dimension dim($V_1$) + dim($V_2$) but I don't know how to deal with such operator constraint to extract dim(range$A$ + range$B$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is a great question. The answer below will suffice. However, I noticed in your question you referred to the maps $A$ and $B$ as "operators". This terminology is only really used when the domain and the codomain of some map $f$ are the same. So, with that said in your questions context $A$ and $B$ are called *linear maps* (note that an operator on a space is a map, we just call it such a name to emphasize that it sends sends elements in the set to elements in the same set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique that is useful in algebra is to try to relate the subspace you are working with (in this case $V_1 \times_W V_2$) with some linear map.

Define a map $C: V_1 \times V_2 \to W$ where $C((v_1, v_2)) = Av_1 - Bv_2$. Note that $C$ is linear, $\ker C = V_1 \times_W V_2$, and $\operatorname{range} C = \operatorname{range}A + \operatorname{range}B$.

By the Rank-Nullity Theorem $$\dim(V_1 \times V_2) = \dim(\ker C) + \dim(\operatorname{range} C)$$ so $$\dim(V_1) + \dim(V_2) = \dim(V_1 \times _W V_2) + \dim(\operatorname{range}A + \operatorname{range}B)$$ and the desired equality follows.